# Write to the same line - Python

Tags: python, txt

I need some help. I want to read from three different txt files. In firs file there is one line, on second and third files I want to read only the second line. I would like to output to the same line. I have tried to get rid of "spaces" in the end of the file with on_off.strip(), on_off.replace(" ","") but it is the same.

code:

```
    f = open(pathToAbsoReport, "r")         
                serial = (f.read(15))                 
    
                h = open(pathON_OFF, "r")               
                on_off = (h.readlines())                
    
                g = open(pathRepeat, "r")
                repeat = (g.readlines())
    
    
                if serial[0] == "6":           
                    d = open(writePath,  "a")
                    d.write(serial + "," + on_off[1] + "," + repeat[1] + "\n")
                    d.close()
```

Output:

```
    6V1920xxxxx0001,544,534,10,327,323,4,283,276,7,OK
    
    ,541,539,2,325,323,2,278,275,3,OK
```

I would like:

```
    6V1920xxxxx0001,544,534,10,327,323,4,283,276,7,OK,541,539,2,325,323,2,278,275,3,OK
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the python-documentary [7.2.1. Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> f.readline() reads a single line from the file; a newline character
> (\n) is left at the end of the string [comment from  user: also for readlines()], and is only omitted on the last
> line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the
> return value unambiguous; if f.readline() returns an empty string, the
> end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by
> '\n', a string containing only a single newline.

```
>>> f.readline()
'This is the first line of the file.\n'
>>> f.readline()
'Second line of the file\n'
>>> f.readline()
''
```

So you can use `rstrip('\n')`:

```
d.write(serial.rstrip('\n') + "," + on_off[1].rstrip('\n') + "," + repeat[1].rstrip('\n') + "\n")
```